# get results without id in org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm using org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient to get data from elasticsearch.
I want to know is it possible to get all documents using RestHighLevelClient for given index?
like http://localhost:9200/test/_search?

Comment: how is this related to Spring Boot and Spring Data Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible.
First of all you need to initialize the client

```
RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(
    RestClient.builder(
            new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http"),
            new HttpHost("localhost", 9201, "http")));
```

then you need to execute a search query.

If you would like to fetch all docs you will have to use the **scrolling** API.

You can find a complete example [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/7.4/java-rest-high-search-scroll.html#java-rest-high-search-scroll-example).

If you do not need all, you can simply use the [search API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/7.4/java-rest-high-search.html#java-rest-high-search).

And don't forget to close the connection when the work is done

```
client.close();
```

Comment: Great, in this case can you please mark your question as "answered"